# Can't install PHP and MySQL on CentOS 5 64 Bits

Tags: mysql, php, centos, yum, installation

I'm getting the following error when trying to install PHP and MySQL form the atomicorp.com repository:

```
[root@x171 ~]# yum -y install mysql-libs php php-gd gd mysql mysql-server mysql-devel mod_auth_mysql.x86_64 php-mysql php-common
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
* atomic: www7.atomicorp.com
* base: mirror.yourwebhoster.eu
* extras: mirror.yourwebhoster.eu
* updates: mirror.yourwebhoster.eu
Setting up Install Process
Resolving Dependencies
--> Running transaction check
---> Package gd.i386 0:2.0.33-9.4.el5_4.2 set to be updated
--> Processing Dependency: pkgconfig for package: gd
--> Processing Dependency: libjpeg.so.62 for package: gd
--> Processing Dependency: libfontconfig.so.1 for package: gd
--> Processing Dependency: libX11.so.6 for package: gd
--> Processing Dependency: libz.so.1 for package: gd
--> Processing Dependency: libXpm.so.4 for package: gd
--> Processing Dependency: libpng12.so.0 for package: gd
--> Processing Dependency: libfreetype.so.6 for package: gd
--> Processing Dependency: libpng12.so.0(PNG12_0) for package: gd
---> Package gd.x86_64 0:2.0.33-9.4.el5_4.2 set to be updated
--> Processing Dependency: libfreetype.so.6()(64bit) for package: gd
--> Processing Dependency: libXpm.so.4()(64bit) for package: gd
--> Processing Dependency: libfontconfig.so.1()(64bit) for package: gd
--> Processing Dependency: libX11.so.6()(64bit) for package: gd
---> Package mod_auth_mysql.x86_64 1:3.0.0-3.2.el5_3 set to be updated
--> Processing Dependency: libmysqlclient.so.15(libmysqlclient_15)(64bit) for package: mod_auth_mysql
--> Processing Dependency: libmysqlclient.so.15()(64bit) for package: mod_auth_mysql
---> Package mysql.i386 0:5.5.16-1.el5.art set to be updated
--> Processing Dependency: libstdc++.so.6(GLIBCXX_3.4) for package: mysql
--> Processing Dependency: libgcc_s.so.1(GCC_3.0) for package: mysql
--> Processing Dependency: libssl.so.6 for package: mysql
--> Processing Dependency: libstdc++.so.6(CXXABI_1.3) for package: mysql
--> Processing Dependency: libcrypto.so.6 for package: mysql
--> Processing Dependency: libgcc_s.so.1(GLIBC_2.0) for package: mysql
--> Processing Dependency: libgcc_s.so.1 for package: mysql
--> Processing Dependency: libncurses.so.5 for package: mysql
--> Processing Dependency: libstdc++.so.6 for package: mysql
---> Package mysql.x86_64 0:5.5.16-1.el5.art set to be updated
---> Package mysql-devel.i386 0:5.5.16-1.el5.art set to be updated
--> Processing Dependency: openssl-devel for package: mysql-devel
---> Package mysql-devel.x86_64 0:5.5.16-1.el5.art set to be updated
---> Package mysql-libs.i386 0:5.5.16-1.el5.art set to be updated
---> Package mysql-libs.x86_64 0:5.5.16-1.el5.art set to be updated
---> Package mysql-server.i386 0:5.5.16-1.el5.art set to be updated
--> Processing Dependency: libaio.so.1(LIBAIO_0.4) for package: mysql-server
--> Processing Dependency: libaio.so.1 for package: mysql-server
--> Processing Dependency: perl(DBI) for package: mysql-server
--> Processing Dependency: libaio.so.1(LIBAIO_0.1) for package: mysql-server
--> Processing Dependency: perl-DBI for package: mysql-server
--> Processing Dependency: perl-DBD-MySQL for package: mysql-server
---> Package mysql-server.x86_64 0:5.5.16-1.el5.art set to be updated
--> Processing Dependency: libaio.so.1(LIBAIO_0.4)(64bit) for package: mysql-server
--> Processing Dependency: libaio.so.1(LIBAIO_0.1)(64bit) for package: mysql-server
--> Processing Dependency: libaio.so.1()(64bit) for package: mysql-server
---> Package php.i386 0:5.3.8-1.el5.art set to be updated
--> Processing Dependency: php-cli = 5.3.8-1.el5.art for package: php
--> Processing Dependency: libgssapi_krb5.so.2 for package: php
--> Processing Dependency: libbz2.so.1 for package: php
--> Processing Dependency: libgmp.so.3 for package: php
--> Processing Dependency: libk5crypto.so.3 for package: php
--> Processing Dependency: libcom_err.so.2 for package: php
--> Processing Dependency: libxml2.so.2 for package: php
--> Processing Dependency: libkrb5.so.3 for package: php
---> Package php.x86_64 0:5.3.8-1.el5.art set to be updated
--> Processing Dependency: libgmp.so.3()(64bit) for package: php
---> Package php-common.i386 0:5.3.8-1.el5.art set to be updated
--> Processing Dependency: libcurl.so.3 for package: php-common
--> Processing Dependency: libidn.so.11 for package: php-common
---> Package php-common.x86_64 0:5.3.8-1.el5.art set to be updated
---> Package php-gd.i386 0:5.3.8-1.el5.art set to be updated
--> Processing Dependency: libt1.so.5 for package: php-gd
---> Package php-gd.x86_64 0:5.3.8-1.el5.art set to be updated
--> Processing Dependency: libt1.so.5()(64bit) for package: php-gd
---> Package php-mysql.i386 0:5.3.8-1.el5.art set to be updated
--> Processing Dependency: php-pdo for package: php-mysql
--> Processing Dependency: libmysqlclient.so.16 for package: php-mysql
--> Processing Dependency: libmysqlclient.so.16(libmysqlclient_16) for package: php-mysql
---> Package php-mysql.x86_64 0:5.3.8-1.el5.art set to be updated
--> Processing Dependency: libmysqlclient.so.16(libmysqlclient_16)(64bit) for package: php-mysql
--> Processing Dependency: libmysqlclient.so.16()(64bit) for package: php-mysql
--> Running transaction check
---> Package bzip2-libs.i386 0:1.0.3-6.el5_5 set to be updated
---> Package curl.i386 0:7.15.5-9.el5_7.4 set to be updated
---> Package e2fsprogs-libs.i386 0:1.39-33.el5 set to be updated
--> Processing Dependency: libdevmapper.so.1.02 for package: e2fsprogs-libs
---> Package fontconfig.i386 0:2.4.1-7.el5 set to be updated
--> Processing Dependency: libexpat.so.0 for package: fontconfig
---> Package fontconfig.x86_64 0:2.4.1-7.el5 set to be updated
---> Package freetype.i386 0:2.2.1-28.el5_5.1 set to be updated
---> Package freetype.x86_64 0:2.2.1-28.el5_5.1 set to be updated
---> Package gmp.i386 0:4.1.4-10.el5 set to be updated
---> Package gmp.x86_64 0:4.1.4-10.el5 set to be updated
---> Package krb5-libs.i386 0:1.6.1-62.el5 set to be updated
--> Processing Dependency: libselinux.so.1 for package: krb5-libs
--> Processing Dependency: libkeyutils.so.1 for package: krb5-libs
--> Processing Dependency: libkeyutils.so.1(KEYUTILS_0.3) for package: krb5-libs
---> Package libX11.i386 0:1.0.3-11.el5_7.1 set to be updated
--> Processing Dependency: xorg-x11-filesystem >= 0.99.2-3 for package: libX11
--> Processing Dependency: libXau.so.6 for package: libX11
--> Processing Dependency: libXdmcp.so.6 for package: libX11
---> Package libX11.x86_64 0:1.0.3-11.el5_7.1 set to be updated
--> Processing Dependency: libXdmcp.so.6()(64bit) for package: libX11
--> Processing Dependency: libXau.so.6()(64bit) for package: libX11
---> Package libXpm.i386 0:3.5.5-3 set to be updated
---> Package libXpm.x86_64 0:3.5.5-3 set to be updated
---> Package libaio.i386 0:0.3.106-5 set to be updated
---> Package libaio.x86_64 0:0.3.106-5 set to be updated
---> Package libgcc.i386 0:4.1.2-51.el5 set to be updated
---> Package libidn.i386 0:0.6.5-1.1 set to be updated
---> Package libjpeg.i386 0:6b-37 set to be updated
---> Package libpng.i386 2:1.2.10-7.1.el5_7.5 set to be updated
---> Package libstdc++.i386 0:4.1.2-51.el5 set to be updated
---> Package libxml2.i386 0:2.6.26-2.1.12 set to be updated
---> Package mysqlclient15.x86_64 0:5.0.90-1.el5.art set to be updated
---> Package mysqlclient16.x86_64 0:5.1.57-1.el5.art set to be updated
---> Package ncurses.i386 0:5.5-24.20060715 set to be updated
---> Package openssl.i686 0:0.9.8e-20.el5 set to be updated
---> Package openssl-devel.x86_64 0:0.9.8e-20.el5 set to be updated
--> Processing Dependency: zlib-devel for package: openssl-devel
--> Processing Dependency: krb5-devel for package: openssl-devel
---> Package perl-DBD-MySQL.x86_64 0:3.0007-2.el5 set to be updated
---> Package perl-DBI.x86_64 0:1.52-2.el5 set to be updated
---> Package php-cli.x86_64 0:5.3.8-1.el5.art set to be updated
--> Processing Dependency: libedit.so.0()(64bit) for package: php-cli
---> Package php-mysql.i386 0:5.3.8-1.el5.art set to be updated
--> Processing Dependency: libmysqlclient.so.16 for package: php-mysql
--> Processing Dependency: libmysqlclient.so.16(libmysqlclient_16) for package: php-mysql
---> Package php-pdo.x86_64 0:5.3.8-1.el5.art set to be updated
---> Package pkgconfig.x86_64 1:0.21-2.el5 set to be updated
---> Package t1lib.i386 0:5.1.2-2.el5.art set to be updated
--> Processing Dependency: libXaw.so.7 for package: t1lib
--> Processing Dependency: libXt.so.6 for package: t1lib
---> Package t1lib.x86_64 0:5.1.2-2.el5.art set to be updated
--> Processing Dependency: libXaw.so.7()(64bit) for package: t1lib
--> Processing Dependency: libXt.so.6()(64bit) for package: t1lib
---> Package zlib.i386 0:1.2.3-4.el5 set to be updated
--> Running transaction check
---> Package device-mapper.i386 0:1.02.63-4.el5 set to be updated
--> Processing Dependency: libsepol.so.1 for package: device-mapper
---> Package expat.i386 0:1.95.8-8.3.el5_5.3 set to be updated
---> Package keyutils-libs.i386 0:1.2-1.el5 set to be updated
---> Package krb5-devel.x86_64 0:1.6.1-62.el5 set to be updated
--> Processing Dependency: libselinux-devel for package: krb5-devel
--> Processing Dependency: e2fsprogs-devel for package: krb5-devel
--> Processing Dependency: keyutils-libs-devel for package: krb5-devel
---> Package libXau.i386 0:1.0.1-3.1 set to be updated
---> Package libXau.x86_64 0:1.0.1-3.1 set to be updated
---> Package libXaw.i386 0:1.0.2-8.1 set to be updated
--> Processing Dependency: libXext.so.6 for package: libXaw
--> Processing Dependency: libXmu.so.6 for package: libXaw
---> Package libXaw.x86_64 0:1.0.2-8.1 set to be updated
--> Processing Dependency: libXext.so.6()(64bit) for package: libXaw
--> Processing Dependency: libXmu.so.6()(64bit) for package: libXaw
---> Package libXdmcp.i386 0:1.0.1-2.1 set to be updated
---> Package libXdmcp.x86_64 0:1.0.1-2.1 set to be updated
---> Package libXt.i386 0:1.0.2-3.2.el5 set to be updated
--> Processing Dependency: libICE.so.6 for package: libXt
--> Processing Dependency: libSM.so.6 for package: libXt
---> Package libXt.x86_64 0:1.0.2-3.2.el5 set to be updated
--> Processing Dependency: libICE.so.6()(64bit) for package: libXt
--> Processing Dependency: libSM.so.6()(64bit) for package: libXt
---> Package libedit.x86_64 0:20090923-3.0_1.el5.rf set to be updated
---> Package libselinux.i386 0:1.33.4-5.7.el5 set to be updated
---> Package php-mysql.i386 0:5.3.8-1.el5.art set to be updated
--> Processing Dependency: libmysqlclient.so.16 for package: php-mysql
--> Processing Dependency: libmysqlclient.so.16(libmysqlclient_16) for package: php-mysql
---> Package xorg-x11-filesystem.noarch 0:7.1-2.fc6 set to be updated
---> Package zlib-devel.x86_64 0:1.2.3-4.el5 set to be updated
--> Running transaction check
---> Package e2fsprogs-devel.x86_64 0:1.39-33.el5 set to be updated
---> Package keyutils-libs-devel.x86_64 0:1.2-1.el5 set to be updated
---> Package libICE.i386 0:1.0.1-2.1 set to be updated
---> Package libICE.x86_64 0:1.0.1-2.1 set to be updated
---> Package libSM.i386 0:1.0.1-3.1 set to be updated
---> Package libSM.x86_64 0:1.0.1-3.1 set to be updated
---> Package libXext.i386 0:1.0.1-2.1 set to be updated
---> Package libXext.x86_64 0:1.0.1-2.1 set to be updated
---> Package libXmu.i386 0:1.0.2-5 set to be updated
---> Package libXmu.x86_64 0:1.0.2-5 set to be updated
---> Package libselinux-devel.x86_64 0:1.33.4-5.7.el5 set to be updated
--> Processing Dependency: libsepol-devel >= 1.15.2-1 for package: libselinux-devel
---> Package libsepol.i386 0:2.0.36-1.el5.art set to be updated
---> Package libsepol.x86_64 0:2.0.36-1.el5.art set to be updated
---> Package php-mysql.i386 0:5.3.8-1.el5.art set to be updated
--> Processing Dependency: libmysqlclient.so.16 for package: php-mysql
--> Processing Dependency: libmysqlclient.so.16(libmysqlclient_16) for package: php-mysql
--> Running transaction check
---> Package libsepol-devel.x86_64 0:2.0.36-1.el5.art set to be updated
---> Package php-mysql.i386 0:5.3.8-1.el5.art set to be updated
--> Processing Dependency: libmysqlclient.so.16 for package: php-mysql
--> Processing Dependency: libmysqlclient.so.16(libmysqlclient_16) for package: php-mysql
--> Finished Dependency Resolution
php-mysql-5.3.8-1.el5.art.i386 from atomic has depsolving problems
  --> Missing Dependency: libmysqlclient.so.16(libmysqlclient_16) is needed by package php-mysql-5.3.8-1.el5.art.i386 (atomic)
php-mysql-5.3.8-1.el5.art.i386 from atomic has depsolving problems
  --> Missing Dependency: libmysqlclient.so.16 is needed by package php-mysql-5.3.8-1.el5.art.i386 (atomic)
Error: Missing Dependency: libmysqlclient.so.16 is needed by package php-mysql-5.3.8-1.el5.art.i386 (atomic)
Error: Missing Dependency: libmysqlclient.so.16(libmysqlclient_16) is needed by package php-mysql-5.3.8-1.el5.art.i386 (atomic)
You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
You could try running: package-cleanup --problems
                        package-cleanup --dupes
                        rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest
The program package-cleanup is found in the yum-utils package.
```

Doesn't mysql-libs have libmysqlclient.so.16(libmysqlclient_16)?

I also tried to install mysql-libs first and then all the rest, but that didn't work either.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Try installing one package at a time. The basic complaint is that php-mysql requires a specific version of libmysqlclient that is apparently not being provided by this repo site.

Comment: I'd definitely try installation with the --skip-broken option and see what doesn't install and work from there.

Comment: Is the repo you are getting stuff from an official Centos repo?

Comment: Further to mdpc's comment... Why are you using the atomic repo? CentOS provides PHP 5.3 now.

Comment: @jasondbecker Atomic keeps PHP updated to the last version while CentOS official repos don't.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you are running into the "feature" of yum on x86_64 systems where `yum install foo` attempts to install `foo.i386` as well. Try

```
[root@x171 ~]# yum -y install mysql-libs.x86_64 php.x86_64 php-gd.x86_64 gd.x86_64 mysql.x86_64 mysql-server.x86_64 mysql-devel.x86_64 mod_auth_mysql.x86_64 php-mysql.x86_64 php-common.x86_64
```

Answer (score 2):

On 64 bit Linux system I got the related error while installing PHP 5.4, so I installed an 'compat' rmp which satisfied the missing dependencies for libmysqlclient (16, 15, 14 ,12) respectively.

You can refer the link below:

http://gettechgo.wordpress.com/2012/12/03/failed-dependency-libmysqlcliet-so-16/